# How to place elements shifted

Tags: android, css, xml, user-interface, layout

I want my buttons in my app to be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy4PK.png

How is that possible and what layouts do you need ? Can someone give me a simple example in xml how to realize this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: No code, no solution.

Comment: I got no code. I made this in photoshop to show you what I want to do. A simple description or idea what layouts to use would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there are various ways of doing this and I highly recommend you lookup the different kind of viewgroups out there such as FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and so forth.

With regards to your question, here is a basic approach.
Now you haven't given me much to work with so it will look pretty much like your image.

Taking advantage of LinearLayouts "stacking" like layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- LayoutA -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- LayoutB -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

       <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- LayoutC -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout (A) has two children which will be "stacked" vertically from top (orientation="vertical") and the two children (B) and (C) have the buttons in which have been "stacked" horizontally from left (orientation="horizontal").

Oh and (C) is in the middle of the screen because of the gravity set on it (layout_gravity="center_horizontal")

If you change the text in your buttons, you may want to either make the width of the buttons wider or use wrap_content.

Have a play and enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks ! That helped a lot. Is there a way to customize the value of the layout_gravity ? So I can move the layout (second button line) a few more pixels to the left or right ?

Comment: You don't have to use layout_gravity on Layout C for example. You could use change it to margin_left="...dp" instead. Or you can use them together and have it ...dp additional from the center of the phone screen.  Oh, you can put minuses in margin to which will make it go the otherway.

Comment: Ok ! Didn't know you can combine these two settings

Comment: Hey, do you know by any chance how to keep the height-width-proportion of these buttons ? Depending on what device I use these buttons are being stretched. Thanks !